# Gui refresh with buffer storage and appending

Tags: java, html

i have an html form that submit  xml as output after submitting first form xml need to keep l somewere and append the next xml created after the gui refresh how can i do  using java?

```
String head = "<dictionary>";

String end = "<dictionary>";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

    buf.append(xml);
}
String dict = buf.toString();

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append(head);
buffer.append(dict);
buffer.append(end);

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your `for` loop it prints only once, so you dont get the second value in the xml string so you need to change the index as follows.

```
    String head = "<dictionary>";
    String end = "</dictionary>";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        buf.append(xml);
    }
    String dict = buf.toString();

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(head);
    buffer.append(dict);
    buffer.append(end);

    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```